# How could I make a re-sizing array?

Tags: java, arrays

Now I know arrays are fixed and their length cannot be changed. But I have to somehow use arrays in such a way that when the first array gets filled, I create a new array of double length and copy the values from the old array into the new array. I have to have this working an infinite amount of times. Also I cannot use array lists or anything under the collections interface.

Comment: Look up `ArrayList`. Thats your solution.

Comment: @Quijx "Also I cannot use array lists or anything under the collections interface."

Comment: Then duplicate the code of ArrayList. It's open-source. Why in hell wouldn't you use the standard, ready-made class that does exactly what you want?

Comment: Like you don't know :p

Comment: Another option is to use arraylists and convert back to array at the end

Comment: well, as you wont look at ArrayList then have you looked at System.arraycopy ? (like copy the source array, to a destination one+1 each time)

Comment: @JBNizet believe me, I would much rather use an arraylist but they are not permitted on this assignment

Comment: You pretty much gave pseudo code of your own solution in your answer: create new array double the size, copy old array to it. So where exactly is the problem?

Comment: So it's an assignment, and it asks you to do what ArrayList is doing. Try to do it yourself, it's not that hard, and if you're stuck, look at the source code of ArrayList.

Comment: why the down vote bellow? @RealSkeptic, I think I just wrote there what you said, isn't? or did I said something wrong?

Comment: @Victor - downvote not mine, but I think it may be because (a) you are supposed to be more specific in an answer, not just give vague guidelines (as opposed to a comment), (b) your formatting is bad, and (c) It's not clear what the name of the field is.

Comment: @RealSkeptic, Thanks, I ask just for the opinion.

Comment: If you can't seem to find back your previously asked questions, click anywhere your username or your profile picture appears as a link, like in top bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own array class, with a int[] as a field, lets say: numbers.
Whenever you need you increase the size you can do:

`int[] tmpArray = new int[size you need]
 copy first to tmp
 numbers = tmp;`

with this the original array will be garbage collected and the field  will have a new array with the capacity you need.

They copy, you can do with your favority method, from System class, Arrays or even a old fashion loop

Answer (score 0):

As you adequately put it, arrays cannot be resized.
You have to allocate a new array and copy the content of the old array.

For example, a class with a dynamically growing array storage might resize itself like this:

```
int[] arr = {1, 2, 3};

void ensureCapacity(int targetSize) {
    if (arr.length < targetSize) {
        arr = Arrays.copyOf(arr, targetSize);
    }
}
```

If your version of Java doesn't have `Arrays.copyOf`, you can do it the good old-fashioned way using `System.arraycopy`:

```
void ensureCapacity(int targetSize) {
    if (arr.length < targetSize) {
        int[] old = arr;
        arr = new int[targetSize];
        System.arraycopy(old, 0, arr, 0, old.length);
    }
}
```